# Telnet to the RabbitMQ Stomp adapter just hung

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, windows-8.1, telnet, stomp

I am using **RabbitMQ server 3.5.6** on **windows 8.1 and Windows 7 x64**.

I have to access the **Stomp Adapter** embedded with the RabbitMQ Server.

So i have configured it from https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

it shows that it is successfully enabled and configured the **rabbitmq_stomp**.

After doing this i have restarted my computer and try to **telnet** to the **localhost 61613** (the default socket of the rabbitmq_stomp) and it just hung in there saying **connecting**.

[image]

**The RabbitMQ server log says:**

```
=INFO REPORT==== 4-Dec-2015::17:53:29 ===
accepting STOMP connection <0.327.0> ([::1]:49397 -> [::1]:61613)
```

**what did i do wrong? any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: I'm running into the same problem as you, may I ask how did you get the RabbitMQ server log? I'm completely new to RabbitMQ. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I find out a way to test the **STOMP** with **RabbitMQ**, you can issue the following command to test it. The solution here is by using `nc`, I didn't find a way using `telnet` under Windows though.

```
echo -e 'CONNECT\naccept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2\n\n\0' | nc -q10 127.0.0.1 61613
```

Normally the client should send the first byte in that protocal, usually something like  `CONNECT\naccept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2\nhost:yourstomp`, needs a **null** byte , in this case is `Ctrl-@`, at the end to terminate, so that would be easier to send via `echo -e` or similar.